# Cities XL not starting after windows reinstall

Tags: technical-issues, cities-xl

I have reinstalled my windows XP and now cities XL is giving error "This application has failed to start because the application configuration is incorrect. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem"
Is there any solution other then reinstalling the whole game again? I think some registry entries will solve the problem but i don't have them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add registry from here http://www.regfiles.net/file/86/
And install vcredist_x86.exe (Visual C++ Redist) from CitiesXL folder